# Await for an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

Is there a way to await for an async function? Something like `yield*` (with an asterisk) will delegate to another generator function.

For example:

```
asyncFunction1 = async () => {
    await promise1;
    await promise2;
}

asyncFunction2 = async () => {
    await asyncFunction1(); // can we do that or it MUST be a promise?
}
```

Comment: It should work as you have written: [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4enwdhgt/). Or is there something I misunderstood?

Comment: I didn't realize that an async function returns a promise. So yes, it should work because of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking a function `async` makes it implicitly return a promise:

> When an `async` function is called, it returns a `Promise`. When the `async` function returns a value, the `Promise` will be resolved with the returned value.  When the `async` function throws an exception or some value, the `Promise` will be rejected with the thrown value.

([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description))

In other words, you can `await` on an async function, even when that function returns a non-Promise value (because that value will be wrapped with a Promise automatically):

```
async function test() {
  return 123;
}

void async function() {
  let value = await test();
  console.log('value', value);
}();
```